# How to I resize an ImageView in the ViewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, image, resize, imageview, screen

I have an imageView that is resized in two different parts of my code. This works great in my textFieldDoneEditing. However, when I use the same code in my viewDidLoad, I get a different sized view. Is there a difference with doing this in the that method?

Here's the code:

```
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;  
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width; 
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0, screenWidth, screenWidth);

    PuzzleImage.frame = frame;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your ViewController is landscape mode, `viewDidLoad` always gets main screen's bounds in portrait mode.

So, solution is `setFrame` in `viewWillAppear` to get right bounds.